# Normal to a hypersurface in curved manifold.

Tags: tensors

The text 
http://web.mit.edu/edbert/GR/gr1.pdf 4.8 surface integration
says that

> We can generalize this by
>   asking for the three-dimensional proper “hypersurface” element normal to any given
>   vector (~et in the case of a spatial volume element at ﬁxed t). What does it mean for a
>   vector to be normal to a hypersurface in a curved manifold? The meaning is practically
>   the same as in Euclidean geometry except that the "***normal is a one-form***" $\tilde{n}$ rather than
>   a vector.

I am relatively new to tensor calculus and differential geometry,  so far i know that metric provides a isomorphism between one-forms and vector as quoted from the text

> Although vectors and one-forms are distinct objects, there is a strong relationship be-
>   tween them. In fact, the linear space of vectors is isomorphic to the dual vector space
>   of one-forms (Wald 1984). Every equation or operation in one space has an equivalent
>   equation or operation in the other space. **This isomorphism can be used to hide the
>   distinction between one-forms and vectors** in a way that simpliﬁes the notation.

I intuitively understand this concept and why because of this we were able to define a dual vector basis as distinct from one-form basis and vector basis. And everything expressed in vector, dual vector basis will be only contavariant rank tensor. But without the metric there is still a distinction between one-form and vector.

My question is then I have always seen normal as being a vector, **why is normal introduced inherently as a one-form here? What is the significance of normal being a one-form as opposed to being a vector?** And similarly surface element is also described as one-form. Is this result valid for every hyper surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal vector, by definition, is orthogonal to any vector tangent to the hypersurface. But what does "orthogonal" mean?

$$\tilde n\cdot\vec v = 0$$

The dot product between vectors is undefined without a metric. But the dot product between a vector and a covector (one-form) is always defined; it's basically the reason that covectors exist. (I use "covector" and "one-form" interchangeably, but there is a slight difference: a covector is an independent object, while a one-form is a *function of vectors* determined by such an object.)

I don't think a surface element should be a one-form, but instead a (contravariant/tangent) [blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_%28geometry%29). They are equivalent by Hodge duality, but I'm pretty sure the duality is unnatural without a metric or a volume-form or something.